# Lenovo R61i - audio not working with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, thinkpad

Has any one got a solution to this problem.
I have installed windows 7 pro and installed audio (coexant) latest driver from the lenovo web site but it still does not work.  I have seen many similar posts but no solution - just the usual - do you have the most recent driver.... etc. Is there any one that has solved this problem out there?
(Driver details: Audio Driver 2.57 MB Normal Version 4.98.5.50)

Comment: A random thing to try: Fool around with BIOS settings that involve your audio device. I doubt that'll help, but hey, it's something you can try.

Comment: Don't know about the technical part, but you get your sound back when you sleep your laptop and then log in. It works in all Lenovos. Until now a solution for getting back sound permanently in not given.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on a Lenovo T61.  The HD audio driver is required as well as the sound card driver itself.  Did you install the HD driver? Have you installed  the Levovo Thinkvantage system tools? [ThinkVantage System Tools](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/TVSU-UPDATE.html)